# Extend a line to find the intersection time on a path

Tags: diagrams, metapost

I'm writing metapost. I have a curve between two points (z0 and z1), and an arbitary point somewhere nearby (z2).

I reflect z2 about the straight line `z0--z1` to give its opposing counterpart, z3. I wish to extend the line `z2--z3` such that it intersects with the curve, so that I can find that intersection point.

I think I can use something like `unitvector(direction 0 of (z0 -- z1))` multipled by `whatever` length, solved by metapost to intersect at `point whatever` of the curve. But I'm not sure how to express that in metapost.

Thank you

[image]

```
beginfig(1)

    u := 1cm;

    z0 = (1u, 2u);
    z1 = (4u, 3u);

    % some curve which does not cross z0--z1
    draw z0{up} .. z1{down};

    % an arbitary point
    z2 = (2u, 3u);
    z3 = z2 reflectedabout(z0, z1);

    draw z0 -- z1 dashed evenly;
    draw z2 -- z3 withcolor red;

    draw z0 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z1 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z2 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z3 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;

    label.bot(btex $z_0$ etex, z0);
    label.bot(btex $z_1$ etex, z1);
    label.top(btex $z_2$ etex, z2);
    label.bot(btex $z_3$ etex, z3);

endfig;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `solve` macro for this kind of problem.

It would be nice to be able to write this:

```
path a;  a = z0{up} .. z1{down};
z4 = whatever[z2,z3] = point whatever of a;
```

but if you do that, then MP will complain that it can't cope with `point (unknown) of known path`.  So you need to use `solve`.  The idea is that you write a macro that gives either a true value or a false value, and feed that to `solve`.  MP will then find the value on the "cutting edge between truth and falsity".  This is documented in *The Metafont Book*, pp.176-177.

Here's my attempt at your problem.

```
beginfig(1)

    u := 1cm;

    z0 = (1u, 2u);
    z1 = (4u, 3u);

    % some curve which does not cross z0--z1
    path a;
    a = z0{up} .. z1{down};
    draw a;

    % an arbitary point
    z2 = (2u, 3u);
    z3 = z2 reflectedabout(z0, z1);

    vardef inline(expr t) = 
       angle unitvector(point t of a - z2) > 
       angle unitvector(point t of a - z3)
    enddef;

    z4 = point solve inline(0,1) of a;

    draw z0 -- z1 dashed evenly;
    draw z2 -- z3 withcolor red;

    draw z0 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z1 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z2 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z3 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z4 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor blue;

    label.bot(btex $z_0$ etex, z0);
    label.bot(btex $z_1$ etex, z1);
    label.top(btex $z_2$ etex, z2);
    label.bot(btex $z_3$ etex, z3);
    label.ulft(btex $z_4$ etex, z4);

endfig;

end.
```

which produces this:

[image]

Note that this will work with an arbitrary curved path `a`.  The only requirement is that the macro should return `true` with the first argument
and `false` with the second argument.  So if the path ran in the reverse direction you would have to change the `>` to a `<` or call it with `inline(1,0)` to reverse true/false values.

Comment: Interesting! Does `solve` binary search for that threshold?

Comment: yes, that's it.  You can see how it's implemented if you look in `plain.mp`

Comment: So this is equivalent to @egreg's solution, just with solving in O(log n) rather than O(n), and a little neater because it's a generalised macro.

Comment: I suppose so, but I mainly wanted to point out the existence of `solve` in `plain.mp` as a general purpose extension to MP's built-in ability to solve linear equations.  It allows you to solve more or less anything that it amenable to a estimate-and-improve technique and it's generally very quick.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the segment `z3--z2` and compute the intersection with `intersectionpoint`

```
beginfig(1)

    u := 1cm;

    z0 = (1u, 2u);
    z1 = (4u, 3u);

    % some curve which does not cross z0--z1
    path p,q;
    p =  z0{up} .. z1{down};
    draw p;

    % an arbitary point
    z2 = (2u, 3u);
    z3 = z2 reflectedabout(z0, z1);

    z5 = z3 + 100(z2 - z3);
    q = z3 -- z5;

    z4 = p intersectionpoint q;

    draw z0 -- z1 dashed evenly;
    draw z3 -- z4 withcolor red;

    draw z0 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z1 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z2 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z3 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z4 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;

    label.bot(btex $z_0$ etex, z0);
    label.bot(btex $z_1$ etex, z1);
    label.rt(btex $z_2$ etex, z2);
    label.bot(btex $z_3$ etex, z3);
    label.top(btex $z_4$ etex, z4);

endfig;

end.
```

[image]

If you don't want to hardcode a multiplier, you can use a slower routine that recomputes extensions of the segment until it intersects the arc.

```
beginfig(1)

    u := 1cm;

    z0 = (1u, 2u);
    z1 = (4u, 3u);

    % some curve which does not cross z0--z1
    path p,q;
    p =  z0{up} .. z1{down};
    draw p;

    % an arbitary point
    z2 = (2u, 3u);
    z3 = z2 reflectedabout(z0, z1);

    n = 0;
    forever:
      n := n+1;
      x5 := x3 + n*(x2 - x3);
      x6 := x3 - n*(x2 - x3);
      y5 := y3 + n*(y2 - y3);
      y6 := y3 - n*(y2 - y3);
      q := z5 -- z6;
      exitif xpart(p intersectiontimes q) > 0;
    endfor

    z4 = p intersectionpoint q;

    draw z0 -- z1 dashed evenly;
    draw z3 -- z4 withcolor red;

    draw z0 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z1 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw z2 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z3 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
    draw z4 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;

    label.bot(btex $z_0$ etex, z0);
    label.bot(btex $z_1$ etex, z1);
    label.rt(btex $z_2$ etex, z2);
    label.bot(btex $z_3$ etex, z3);
    label.top(btex $z_4$ etex, z4);

endfig;

end.
```

You probably also need a check for limiting the search in case the line doesn't really intersect the arc.

Comment: Where does the 100 come from, in your `z5 = z3 + 100(z2 - z3);` ? Is this just extending the line by a hardcoded distance, assuming that's long enough to pass through the curve?

My question is how to have metapost solve to calculate that distance, rather than to hardcode an amount. It may also be negative, if the curve is below the dashed line.

Comment: @KateF 100 is a pretty big value; define `z6=z3-100(z2-z_3)` and `q=z5--z6`. You might use a slower routine for extending the segment in steps until `intersectiontimes` returns something.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is how to have metapost solve to find this length.